# Гордость и предубеждение и зомби

Tags: пунктуация

Сейчас в кинотеатрах идёт фильм "Гордость и предубеждение и зомби" ("Pride and Prejudice and Zombies"). Заинтересовало, а нужна ли здесь запятая перед второй "и"? С одной стороны повторяющийся союз, а с другой - "Гордость и предубеждение" здесь выступают как устойчивое словосочетание, отсылающее к роману Джейн Остин.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Даже если бы "гордость и предубеждение" не вызывали никаких аллюзий, запятая перед "зомби" не нужна - согласно Розенталю,

[§87. Однородные члены, соединенные повторяющимися союзами](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/43.htm)

Там к пункту 5 есть славное примечание с разбором полётов на примерах:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Применительно к нашему случаю парную группу образуют аккурат "гордость и предубеждение".

В том же параграфе есть ещё интересненькое по теме повторяющихся союзов (пункт 8):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Нет. Вы совершенно правильно трактуете, это союзы разного уровня, первый связывает только "гордость" и "предубеждение", второй эту конструкцию целиком "гордость и предубеждение" с "зомби". Здесь иначе трудно трактовать, очень уж разный уровень противопоставления - двух близких отвлеченных качеств и вполне конкретного (или конкретных - не знаю, не смотрел) зомби.

Впрочем, остается гипотетическое предположение, что содержание фильма изменит оценку. Но вряд ли, тогда б и в оригинальном английском названии была бы запятая.

Answer (score 1):

Честно говоря, не знаю, о чем сюжет фильма. Но если в самом деле он имеет отношение к известному произведению "Гордость и предубеждение", то запятую и в самом деле ставить не надо. С другой стороны, англичане кавычки, обозначая название книги или песни, ставят редко, а наши "локализаторы", возможно, просто "скалькировали". Как варианты возможного написания: "Гордость и предубеждение" и зомби; Гордость и предубеждение плюс зомби.